# How to wait all asynchronous operations?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-await

I use recursive function to do something

```
public async void walk(StorageFolder folder)
{
   IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> subDirs = null;
   subDirs = await folder.GetFoldersAsync();
   foreach (var subDir in subDirs)
   {
      var dirPath = new Profile() { FolderPath = subDir.Path};
      db.Insert(dirPath);
      walk(subDir);
   }
   tbOut.Text = "Done!";
}
```

So, I want that tbOut.Text = "Done!"; will be done only after all iterations ends. At now it's happenning at the same time while iterations under process. If I run this function like that

```
walk(fd);
tbOut.Text = "Done!";
```

the result still the same. How to wait when this function will ends completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't await the completion of your sub-calls to your walk function.
So all you have to do is change it to `await walk(subDir)`. However, since you can't await a void function you'll have to change it a bit to make it work.
To make your walk function awaitable change the return type to `Task` like so:

```
public async Task walk(StorageFolder folder)
```

Comment: Indeed, you should almost *never* have a `void` async method... they're basically only present to allow event handlers to be asynchronous.